Is there a standardized way to use public/private keys as authentication for a web service?
I am building a web service that knows nothing about its users. I simply store encrypted shares/public keys and any metadata that is received from a user is also sent/stored encrypted. Anything dealing with private keys happens on the client-side and it is up to the client to export their private key for safe-keeping in the event a cookie is removed.
The service I'm building makes heavy use of elliptic curve cryptography via a publicly verifiable secret sharing scheme.
Is there a standardized method of authenticating with an HTTP service this way? I've spent many years using OAuth and other means but can't say I've seen a similar implementation... outside of decrypting a PGP message and providing the token the server encrypted with your public key. I don't want to reinvent the wheel and follow some sort of standard if possible.
In the initial standup of the frontend, I was setting a cookie with the private key, deriving the public key from it, and querying the anonymous participant from the public key on the backend. If no key was in the cookies, the client could either generate a new identity or upload their exported private key to set the cookie and see their previously created secrets or shares.
Things will eventually migrate to local storage so there is no private key left behind on a tab close unless there is a standardized means of doing this or I'm told it is ill-advised. Any help is appreciated.

You mean like an X.509 certificate?

@user207421 Yes, the export is a SEC1 of their private key - but the entire cert is not stored in a cookie, only the needed data.

In security it's almost always the best approach to use tried and tested algorithms/protocols for authentication. It's too easy to make mistakes and produce a solution that's insecure.
Based on what you've said, where your looking to only use a keypair for this, HTTP message signature could be an option - https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc9421.html - this is a standard way for a client to authenticate with a service

Most definitely, as was the reasoning asking for a standardized way. The ECC curve I'm using is supported in the RFC so thanks, @robert-dyke. This is exactly what I was looking for. Marking as the answer.

Since you`re looking for a standardized method of authenticating with an HTTP service while maintaining user privacy through encryption and client-side key management,you might consider JSON web takens (JWT) with asymmetric cryptography.
here's a high-level overview of how you could implement it:

user authentication: when a user logs in or creates an account  the server generates  a jwt is encypted using the user's public key.
client-side storage: the client stores the jwt securely, either in memory or in local storage. since its encrypted with the users public key, only the corresponding private key can decrypt it.
3.authorization: when the client makes requests to the server, it includes the jwt in the request  headers. the server descrypts the jwt using the users private key (which should be stored securely on the client side) to authentication the user and authorize the request.
4.Token enquiry and refresh: you can also implement token expiry and refresh mechanisam to enhance security. when a token experies the client can use a refresh token to obtain a new jwt without having to log in again.
:token revocation: implement mechanisam for token revocation in case a user wants to  revoke access or if a token is compromissed.
jwt with asymmet cryptography provides a standarized and secure way to authenticate users while maintaining privacy and security. it's widely used and supported by many libraries and framework, making it a good choice for your scenario.
remember to handle key mangement securely and follow best practices for cryptographic operations to ensure the integrity and confidentially of your user's data.


I appreciate this, I'm familiar with JWTs and have a pretty firm grasp on the cryptography involved in this as well as the more complex schemes in the original post. I was trying to keep things lightweight and as simple as possible without adding too many abstractions but this will work. I generally opt for opaque tokens so I'm not cramming fine-grained permissions into a JWT, but the service is simple enough to contain them. Thank you.
